# Circumventing variance checks via the map method

Tags: scala

`Set` is invariant in its type parameter, so obviously this won't work:

```
val set: Set[Any] = Set[Int](1, 2, 3)
```

But then why does this work?

```
val set: Set[Any] = Set[Int](1, 2, 3).map(identity)
```

Can anyone explain it? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `identity` takes a type parameter. In this case, the type parameter to `identity` is inferred as `Any`, so what is passed to `map` is `identity[Any]` (an `Any => Any` function). `map` expects an `Int => A` for some type `A`. Since functions are contravariant in their argument types, `Any => Any` can be passed there. So, what your code does is create a new set by mapping each of the original set's elements to have type `Any`. The full types can be written out like this:

```
val set: Set[Any] = Set[Int](1, 2, 3).map[Any, Set[Any]](identity[Any])
```